# Python: Pandas Dataframe MultiIndex select data based on Index values gives empty result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe that has multiple index (latitude, longitude, and time) with the data being windspeed. I want to select based on one latitude, longitude location. When I try this, it returns an empty result. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is part of my original dataframe:

[image]

```
df=df.query('latitude =='+str(24.549999)+ 'and longitude=='+str(-126.870003))
df
```

returns this:

[image]

completely empty like it couldn't find what I was looking for. What am I doing wrong here? Also is there a way to round the index values so for example latitude and longitude are two decimal places latitude=24.55 and longitude=-126.87?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are facing this problem because the column **'latitude','longitude'** and **'time'** are of type string so to resolve it:

```
df=df.reset_index()
```

Now use `astype()` method and `to_datetime()` method:

```
df[['latitude', 'longitude']]=df[['latitude', 'longitude']].astype(float)
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

Finally:

```
df = df.set_index(['latitude', 'longitude','time'])
```

Now If you run your code:

```
df=df.query('latitude =='+str(24.549999)+ 'and longitude=='+str(-126.870003)
```

You will get your desired output

Comment: Hmm I tried the above and it is still returning empty. I would think it would return the windspeeds per time for the given location.

Comment: try `df.query('latitude == 24.549999 and longitude== -126.870003')`

Comment: df=df.query('latitude == 24.549999 and longitude== -126.870003') still returns empty

Comment: since it is working on my side....so let's try out with `loc` accessor.....try: `df.loc[(24.549999,-126.870003)]`

Comment: This gives me a "KeyError: 24.549999"

Comment: I figured out why it isn't selecting. When I print out the df.index.values it gives much higher precision: 24.549999237060547, -126.87000274658203. so the query command with these in it works! Is there a way to round these index values so I can select by 24.55 and -126.87? Not sure where this artificial precision is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok so after I printed the actual values of the dataframe instead of relying on what was displayed, I see that there is much higher precision:

```
df.index.values
```

[image]

So I decided to alter Anurag Dabas answer above to do the following:

```
df[['latitude']]=df[['latitude']].astype(float).applymap('{:,.2f}'.format)
df[['longitude']]=df[['longitude']].astype(float).applymap('{:,.2f}'.format)
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = df.set_index(['latitude', 'longitude','time'])
df
```

[image]

```
df.index.values
```

[image]

and then the following works! Thanks!

```
df.loc[('24.55','-126.87')]
```

[image]